podman containers running under a snap package aren't visible by host's podman
I'm running Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu, installed as a Snap package. If I open the terminal in Visual Studio Code and use it to run a podman container - everything works fine, except that if I run podman on a local terminal, it doesn't see anything running:
$ podman ps -aq | wc -l
0

I can see the processes running in ps, with my user ID:
$ ps auxfw
...
odeda      39121  0.0  0.0  12216  2724 ?        Ss   10:16   0:00  \_ /usr/bin/conmon --api-version 1 -c 7cd9293c0ed384bbebda322d366cefa2890502be3ca
odeda      39123  0.0  0.0  11444  6720 pts/0    Ss+  10:16   0:00  |   \_ nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;
100100     39156  0.0  0.0  11912  3204 pts/0    S+   10:16   0:00  |       \_ nginx: worker process
100100     39157  0.0  0.0  11912  2884 pts/0    S+   10:16   0:00  |       \_ nginx: worker process
...

And I can see the storage files for podman in the Snap's tree:
ls -la ~/snap/code/current/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay-containers/
total 8
drwx------ 1 odeda odeda 206 Dec 27 10:16 .
drwx------ 1 odeda odeda 236 Dec 27 10:36 ..
drwx------ 1 odeda odeda  16 Dec 27 10:16 7cd9293c0ed384bbebda322d366cefa2890502be3caa60854207968a31d4bf08
-rw-r--r-- 1 odeda odeda  64 Dec 27 10:16 containers.lock
-rw------- 1 odeda odeda 533 Dec 27 10:16 volatile-containers.json

I want to work on the running container using podman exec and such - but the podman on the host doesn't see the container:
$ podman exec -ti somecontainer /bin/bash
Error: no container with name or ID "somecontainer" found: no such container

I can run such things fine from the Visual Studio Code's terminal view - but as it is otherwise pretty terrible for serious terminal work, I'd rather not.
I'm guessing this is an artifact of the Snap containment. How do I tell the host's podman to see the podman inside the Snap containment?
